# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Android's [second moderator election](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Flow] 
[image: onik]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://android.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/3).

Comment: Congrats to you both!

Comment: Congratulations and welcome to the mod squad!

Comment: But I suppose I'd better say congrats...

Comment: Congratulations! And all the best for your diamond life here!

Comment: Congratulations guys and all the best! :)

Comment: Congratulations and good luck!

Comment: If anyone wants my view on losing, go look at the chat history.

Comment: Congrats to you both!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to all of those who put themselves out there as candidates, whether they succeeded in being elected or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I have got over losing (I think), time for this.

I just wanted to personally thank everyone that took part and voted, and also every one of the 16 people that chose me as their preferred candidate.

If we ever have another election, then maybe I can win this time - maybe more people will vote for me.

Congratulations to the two winners, Flow and onik - well done :)

If I ever get caught up in my thoughts again, direct me to this post please - and thanks to Izzy for calming me down Yesterday on the chat :)

You never know - maybe two moderators will drop out for some reason and I will get instated ;)

Just let me say thanks to everyone involved - and congrats to the winners.